# Is it possible to run a self hosting OWIN web api inside WinForms (C#)?

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am trying to migrate my self-hosting OWIN WebApiService from a Windows Service app to WinForms. Here's my Startup.cs code:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/auth/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(31),
            //owin providers go here, doesn't matter
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseWebApi(ConfigureWebApi());
    }

    private HttpConfiguration ConfigureWebApi()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.None;
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        return config;
    }
```

Then, the web service :

```
public static class WebService
    {
        static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public static void Run()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        var _ip = "localhost";
        var _port = "1532";
        var url = _ip + ':' + _port;

        try
        {
            WebApp.Start<Startup>(url);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.ErrorFormat("Error on starting web service. Exception : {0}.", ex.Message);
            return;
        }
        log.Info("Service has been started.");
    }

}
```

As a windows service, it's all going fine and all is working. But when I'm trying to run the web service from Winforms app (both from Program.cs or from my form code) - it's looking OK, but I cannot connect to the service nether via  HTTP clients (Chrome, Postman etc.), not via my HTTP client code.

Is is possible to host Web Api in Winforms? Anyone Can help?

P.S. Firewall is turned off. Port also doesn't matter, I tried at least five.

Comment: Are you running VS as administrator?

Comment: shouldn't `http://` be added to url? also, are you sure that you are not hitting `catch` block?

Comment: Yes, VS is running with admin permissions.

Comment: I'm sure I'm not hitting a catch, as for 'http' - on WS it was'nt required. But thanks, I'll try.

Comment: Adding HTTP did the trick! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As [ieaglle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183267/ieaglle) mentioned, adding "HTTP" before the IP did the trick.